# Template for turn-based multiplayer iOS games like Words With Friends?

Tags: ios, game-engine

I'd like to start making more "social" games, and I think that turn-based asynchronous games have a lot of opportunity. However, I would imagine the backend for such a game is pretty involved, so it would be ideal if there were a template or third party solution (paid is fine) that I could implement so that I could spend more time developing my game instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

[Apple's Game Center](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html) gives you a framework for turn-based games. There is much [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/gamecenter/) along with good videos from WWDC (Apple developer ID required to view).

> Multiplayer games provide the ultimate challenge and have created one
>   of the most compelling genres in the App Store. See how Game Center is
>   taking gaming on iOS a step further with the addition of local
>   multiplayer support. Learn about improvements to the turn-based and
>   online multiplayer APIs and new capabilities for sending invites and
>   having a re-match.

Here are a few detailed tutorials with source code:

[beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1)

[how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use our company (Trymph) API that are targeted to support turn-based mobile games like Word with Friends. It has already been used in a number of similar styled games. Checkout https://www.trymph.com/